# awk: utilizing values from one file to search in another file

Tags: awk, range

I have two different files, one with about 2 million + lines of chr, base pair site, and methylation calls. So basically these are all the CpG sites within a genome.

```
chr1 163881 163881 100 2 0
chr1 163896 163896 100 2 0
chr1 163927 163927 100 2 0
chr1 163994 163994 100 2 0
```

I then have another file that has a gene stable ID, chromosome, and the genes start and end.

```
GeneId              chr     start       end
ENSBTAG00000000010  chr21   34209956    34223394
ENSBTAG00000000141  chr11   67778940    67807964
ENSBTAG00000000246  chr29   8891472     9112311
ENSBTAG00000000265  chr22   37781491    38082210
ENSBTAG00000000309  chr13   70704649    71533711
```

I want to search for sites that fall into the range of the genes in my second file. I have an awk command that does this(below), but does not take into consideration what chromosome the site is on... so I end up getting sites that fall into the ranges from each chromosome.

`awk 'FNR==NR {A[$2]=$0;next} {for(i in A){if(i>$3 && i<$4){print A[i] FS $NF}}}' file1.txt file.txt`

I am having trouble incorporating in checking to see if the chromosome is a match as well before performing this command.

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: How do the chr fields in the two files correspond? There aren't any identical ones in your sample data.

Comment: My sample data looks like such chr29 39448 39448 60 6 4. I pulled this from my sample file, it would not fall into the chr29 range in my second file, but it was the first one I could grab.

Comment: When I need to do something like this, I put conditional code that examines the current FILENAME to parse and save required data needed for subsequent files. Sorry I can't be more specific.